# Accessing "Measurement System" unit names (kg/lb, m/in, etc) in C#

Tags: c#, regional

Windows allows configuration of `Measurement system` to `Metric` or `U.S.` Is there a way to use this setting to read (abbreviated) unit names in C#?

e.g. when displaying a weight in `Metric` I want to show `kg` but in `U.S.` I want to show `lb`. Similarly for length, volume, etc.

I've looked at SystemInformation, CultureInfo, Configuration, and Globalization, but didn't see anything obvious. Did I miss something or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the best you can do is to determine if your culture is metric or not and then handle it yourself. I don't think there's any built in formatting? I may be wrong though, but I cannot find any reference to it anywhere.

This will allow you to determine if your culture is metric or not:

```
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);
    bool isMetric = regionInfo.IsMetric;
```

Comment: @GenericTypeTea, thanks it seems like this is the way to go. Seems odd that configuring metric/us doesn't give a way to access the units, I wonder what it's used for ... something to investigate when I'm bored :)

Comment: If you find a better answer, be sure to let us know.

Answer (score -1):

@GenericTypeTea is right about the `RegionInfo` being the place to look.

Additionally F# contains a lot of features for working with units of measure. It might make sense to build some of what you need in F# and call it from C#.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/andrewkennedy/archive/2008/08/29/units-of-measure-in-f-part-one-introducing-units.aspx) and the subsequent posts for information about F# and units of measure.

Comment: @Mike Two, thanks I read the blog post and there are some posts on SO about it also. The units stuff in F# looks interesting but it appears you still have to know the units you're using (e.g. you have to know you're using kg vs lb) which is what I wanted to get from the system configuration. I'm not familiar with F# though, so I may have misunderstood what I was reading.